# $ \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-(A + \sum_{k=1}^{4} B_k e^{-j k \pi \sin(\theta)})} \, d\theta $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, signal-processing

I am trying to evaluate the following integral:

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-(A + \sum_{k=1}^{4} B_k e^{-j k \pi \sin(\theta)})} \, d\theta
$$

where $A$ and $B_k$ are constants, $k$ is an integer, and the integral is taken over $\theta$ from 0 to $2\pi$.

I am interested in understanding if there is any additional insights into this integral. Can someone provide guidance?

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Is $j = \sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: @JohnBarber yes